# Unexpected (string, string, string) error when running the script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running a script to generate a certificate and it runs through and creates the certificates becomes up with this error:

```
Error   
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
createCertificates  @ Code.gs:51
```

The code in question that is in line 51 is:

```
empSlide.replaceAllText("<<Date>>", Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd, MMMM, yyyy"));
```

Comment: The parameters are supposed to Date(),String,String [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) Evidently you variable date is not a Date() object.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) requires the following parameters:

| Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | Date | a Date to format as a String |
| timeZone | String | the output timezone of the result |
| format | String | a format per the SimpleDateFormat specification |

In your scenario the first parameter is given as a `String` instead of a `Date`, and that generates the error. The variable `date`, as shown in line 51, is a string.

I am going to assume that you store the date in a string like `"YEAR-MONTH-DAY"`, please correct me if I am wrong. In that case you can easily fix the script by calling the `Date` constructor like this:

```js
  var date = new Date("1994-11-30");
```